# ConstraintLayout 1.1.0 different from 1.0.2, is it a bug?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

If I use 1.0.2, the 3 images' width is average, and the height of them is computed by the radio which I set. If I use 1.1.0, the height of them is `0dp` and I can't see nothing, unless I set
`android:layout_height="match_parent"`
in the root `ConstraintLayout`.

Is it a bug? Here is my code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/iv1"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/iv0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/iv2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/iv1"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [the updated document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#DimensionConstraints), the layout behavior has changed in [ConstraintLayout 1.1.0](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/04/constraintlayout-110.html):

> **`WRAP_CONTENT` : enforcing constraints (Added in 1.1)**
>   If a dimension is set to `WRAP_CONTENT`, in versions before 1.1 they will be treated as a literal dimension -- meaning, constraints will not limit the resulting dimension. While in general this is enough (and faster), in some situations, you might want to use `WRAP_CONTENT`, yet keep enforcing constraints to limit the resulting dimension. In that case, you can add one of the corresponding attribute:
>
> - `app:layout_constrainedWidth=”true|false”`
> - `app:layout_constrainedHeight=”true|false”`

So, in the new version, this line in your XML is taking effect:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

You can fix the problem with:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```

as written in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48498412/9298629).

---

## Updated:

I misunderstood the question. As [KongDa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6861437/) commented, the problem is not fixed with:

```
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```

The problem is fixed with:

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.333"
```

In a minimal sample app, I checked its behavior as follows.

### Step 1: ConstraintLayout 1.0.2

The height is not zero.

[image]

### Step 2: ConstraintLayout 1.1.0

The height becomes zero.

[image]

### Step 3: ConstraintLayout 1.1.0

The problem is fixed with `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.333"`:

[image]

So, the layout XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/iv1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.333" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/iv0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/iv2"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.333" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/iv1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.333" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you!! But your fix method seems don't effect in my code, and I set `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"` to solved my problem. Thank you !

Comment: @KongDa I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. I checked the behavior step by step, and updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, Completely correct， Thanks for your perfect answer！